# Find cell in table, add text after font class using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this code...

```
<td valign="top">
    <a title="Test Title" class="class1 class2" href="http://www.test.com/product/test123.htm">
        Test Link Text
    </a>
    <img width="5" height="5" src="/images/clear1x1.gif">
    <br>
    <font class="text">Test Text</font>
</td>
```

How do I Find this particular cell, unique to test123.htm, and add text after  using jQuery?

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: `$('.class1[href$="test123.html"]').closest('td').after('text');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("td a[href$='test123.htm']").parent().append("your text");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a.class1.class2[href$="test123.htm"]').closest('td').after("text");
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/RVwmF/1